# How to calculate the success rate against non-occurring events?

Tags: probability, average, percentages

I am calculating a football team's success rate of`Shots Saved`against the opposition's`Shots On Target`for every match. It's very simple, but I have come across something that I need some clarity and perspective on:

If a football team did not register a single shot on target, should the opposition receive`0.00%`for`Shots Saved`as they did not save any shots,`100.00%`because they didn't fail to save any shots and shouldn't be penalised, or would I go with`50.00%`because if a shot were to have occurred, it may have been saved, or may not have been saved (Schrödinger's paradox)?

At the moment, I've left it at`0.00%`but it has a negative impact when averaging the success rate over a number of matches. Technically, it's true, but it also seems to penalise a team when the event occurring was possibly prevented due to another part of their game, which should possibly be rewarded?

Your opinions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to quantifying $\frac00$ which is undefined. Do not take a reading if this occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Foreman, that makes perfect sense! Problem solved.